# Problem: failed to create task or type testng. Cause: The name is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, testng

i´ve got a little problem to run a testng test. I invoke the test with a ant task which returns following error message:

`BUILD FAILED

/**/build.xml:136: Problem: failed to create task or type testng

Cause: The name is undefined.

Action: Check the spelling.

Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.

Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.`

The ant task looks like this:

```
<target name="test-start" depends="test-compile" description="Runs the TestNG tests">
    <testng 
        suitename="pseudo test"
        haltOnFailure="true"
        verbose="2"
        groups="pseudoTest">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <classfileset dir="${build.testclasses.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    </testng>
</target>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${extralib.dir}/testng-5.13.1.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${build.testclasses.dir}" />
</path>
```

This is the test class:

> package **.pseudotest;
>
> import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
>   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>
> public class PseudoTest {
>
> @Test(groups = { "pseudoTest" })
>     public void aSingleTest() {
>         assert false : "The simple test failed and does not return true";
>     }
>   }

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

BVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add the TestNG tasks to Ant.  It doesn't know what class to run when it encounters the `<testng>` tag.

Comment: This solved my problem.  
I added  
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${extralib.dir}/testng5.13.1.jar" />

to the build.xml.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem installing:
**plugin Java EE Base** 
and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

me to I just now solved this problem installing: plugin Java EE Base and the problem was solved.